# Could not or load main class in java

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm doing a homework about read&write file in Java. I've written codes in eclipse and my project works well in Windows. But I'll submit my project to school's Linux servers and the teacher will try to open in that platform.

When I try to work my project in Linux, there is an error

> couldn't find or load Main class Main..input.txt...output.txt.

(I'm trying to start my program with `java Main../input.txt../output.txt` command in Linux.)

```
Scanner scan;

 try{
scan=new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));    
}
catch(Exception error)
{
System.err.println("Error"+error.getMessage());
}
```

I've used that codes to read from an input file. and my file hierarchy; homework/src/main.java. input.txt and output.txt are under the homework, near the src.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you're just missing spaces between your arguments - it should be `java Main ../input.txt ../output.txt`

Comment: Linux file names are case sensitive. E.g. Main and main are different names. If your class name is Main, then file name should be Main.java as well.

Comment: Post your whole class code, it looks like there us some problem in method  signature.

Comment: There is some problem with the escape characters over here "input.txt".Try some combinations over here you will surely crack this .

Comment: Have a look at this article , i guess this will surely help you out .https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Fall12/slides/L08_FilesInputOutput.pdf